# call methode from one class in another (swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

What I want to do is create a method in one class of my iOS app and then call that method from other classes in my app. Could someone explain exactly what I need to do to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated as all my attempts so far have failed!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Principle
{
    var name:String = ""
    func get_name() -> String
    {
        return self.name
    }
}


class School
{
    var princ:Principle = Principle()
    init()
    {
        princ.name = "Mike"
        println(princ.get_name())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass : OptionalSuperClass, OptionalProtocol1 {
    var myProperty:String
    var myOptionalProperty:String? 

    // More properties...

   func doIt(a:Int) -> Int {
        return a 
                           }


  var a = MyClass() 
  a.doIt(1)
```

Comment: Could you please add a bit more context?

Comment: What do you mean? It was a general question.

Comment: Usually you should explain why you think that your code is the appropriate solution. (Yes, the accepted answer has no context either, that's a bad example.) The better you explain in your answer, the better it will be received.